# Mysql-CodeIhniter-Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedure, mariadb

estoy queriendo consumir desde MySql datos y retornos (Parametros Out) de mi Stored en MySql, funciona bien cuando realizo una consulta, pero cuando en el stored envío parámetros incorrectos como en el ejemplo que publico (lenguaje inválido) retorno en el Stored el código de error y su descripcion (`par_ret`, `par_ret_txt`) en los parámetros que son de salida (OUT), con lo cual desde en modelo que arme es imposible acceder al objeto de retorno de query, con el error

`Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object.`

Entiendo que el problema radica en que al no ser una consulta, y al no tener error la consulta (Solo devuelve parámetros de salida) es un gris, ahora los datos del objeto del resultado de la consulta estan, ya que los veo en el var-dump, pero son inaccesibles, alguna idea?

Mi codigo del controlador es:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {



  /**
     * Call procedure
     * @param $procName string procedure name
     * @param $params null|string
     * @return null|CI_DB_result procedure array results
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('startsWith');

    }


    public function callProcedure($procName, $params){
        $vRet =  null;

        $sql = "CALL " . $procName."(";
        $results = null;

        $params = $this->processProcedureParams($params);

        $sql = $sql.$params['in']. ")";

        //El resultado del Query siempre es TRUE y es un Objeto  (nunca viene false)
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows() > 0){ //Aqui siempre da error cuando el query devuelve parámetros de salida solamente.
            $vRet['data'] = $this->db->query($sql)->result_object();
        }else{
            $vRet['data'] = null;
        }

        $outSql = null;
        foreach ($params['out'] as $param){
            if($outSql == null){
                $outSql = "SELECT ". $param . " as ".substr($param, 1);
            } else {
                $outSql = $outSql . ", ". $param . " as ".substr($param, 1);
            }
        }
        if($outSql != null){
            $vRet['params_output'] = $this->db->query($outSql)->result()[0];
        }

        return $vRet;
    }

    /**
     * @param $params
     * @return array|
     */

    private function processProcedureParams($params){
        $processed = null;
        $outParams = array();

        if($params != null){
            if( is_array($params) ){
                foreach ($params as $param){
                    if($processed == null){
                        if(startsWith($param, "@")){
                            $processed = $param;
                            $outParams[] = $param;
                        } else {
                            $processed = "'".$param."'";
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(startsWith($param, "@")){
                            $processed = $processed.", ".$param;
                            $outParams[] = $param;
                        } else {
                            $processed = $processed.", '".$param."'";
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(startsWith($params, "@")){
                    $processed = $params;
                    $outParams[] = $params;
                } else {
                    $processed = "'".$params."'";
                }
            }
        }

        $result['in'] = $processed;
        $result['out'] = $outParams;

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Les paso el Var_dump:

[image: Var_dump]

Les paso el Fragmento del Stored Procedure:

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `viaje_filtro_viaje`(in `par_tkn_trc_own` varchar(128) charset utf8mb4
    , in `par_lnj` int
    , out `par_ret` int
    , out `par_ret_txt` varchar(255) charset utf8mb4
)
    READS SQL DATA
proc_exit:begin
/* 
  ==================================================================
  = nombre sp:viaje_filtro_viaje
  =    obtengo listado de viajes para la empresa del usuario dueño del token
  =         - par_tkn_trc_own: token
  =         - par_lnj: lenguaje
  =         - par_ret: numerico del retorno 
  =         - par_ret_txt: descripcion del retorno 
  ==================================================================
  = retornos
  =     1: lenguaje inválido 
  ==================================================================
  */
#-- declare tmp_exists,tmp_itinerario_sec,tmp_poi int;
#-- declare tmp_visibilidad tinyint;

    #--tkn_owner---
    #transaction owner 
    declare to_par_pers_id,to_user_empresa int default null;
    declare to_par_user_name varchar(40);
    declare to_par_es_adm tinyint; # rol que determina si puede o no cargar resto de usuarios
    declare to_par_pers_rol tinyint; 

    #--tkn_owner---

    #--Valido el Lenguaje
    if not fn_lng_isvalid(par_lnj)=1 then
        set par_ret = 1;
        set par_ret_txt='lenguaje inválido';
        select null as ret;
        leave proc_exit;        
    end if;


end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, en general te recomiendo no poner imagenes cuando puedes poner el contenido en formato texto. Un saludo :)

Comment: Buenas, dale, si lo que pasa es que al insertar el Var_Dump no habia manera de que me lo fomateara correctamente con la opcion de codigo. por eso recurri a la imagenes. Dale la próxima busco una manera de que lo haga correctamente. Gracias y saludos.